# What (39) processor represents in /proc/[pid[/stat file?

Tags: linux, filesystems, linux-kernel, proc, top

As per procfs man

> ```
>  /proc/[pid]/stat
>  (39) processor  %d  (since Linux 2.2.8)
>                         CPU number last executed on.
> ```

I can see, there is `-1` value for some tasks

```
$ cat /proc/1185/task/1283/stat | awk '{print $39}'
-1
```

or

```
$ cat /proc/1283/stat | awk '{print $39}'
-1
```

Top shows `3` for this thread. (in thread mode and selecting P       = Last Used Cpu (SMP) field)

What does this `-1` signifies, which processor number it corresponds to?

Also, why this number is greater than existing cpu sometimes,

```
$ cat /proc/1800/stat | awk '{print $39}'
17
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/online
0-15
$ ps -eLo pid,psr | grep 1800
 1800  14
```

What exactly (39) processor represents in /proc/[pid[/stat file ?

Seems, like lack of documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This is my silly mistake

I am adding here instead of deleting , in case someone also does this mistake

> ```
>  comm  %s
>                         The filename of the executable, in parentheses.  This is  visible  whether  or
>                         not the executable is swapped out.
> ```

If comm has space/s, No of fields differ and 39th field doesn't remain 39th being split by space.